# Setting up controller and views for Kentico Cloud API and .NET

Tags: .net, kentico, kentico-kontent, kentico-mvc

I'm having the worst luck with the documentation for Kentico Cloud and .NET.
I'm looking to get my controller and views organized so they can display on another page (not main view but accessed via navbar) and then click on the post to see the full details of said post.

I've provided my current controller as well as my Posts View, the template view is set up but won't let me display correctly for this question.

I've set up my models and those are fine and have no errors when writing out any code.

```
    BlogController : Controller
    {
        IDeliveryClient client = DeliveryClientBuilder
            .WithProjectId("<ProjectID>")
            .Build();

        [Route("blog")]
        [Route("blog/p/{page}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Posts()
        {
            // Gets all content items
            // Note: Using the <object> generic parameter produces strongly typed objects, based on "system.type"
            DeliveryItemListingResponse<Blog> response = await client.GetItemsAsync<Blog>(
                new EqualsFilter("system.type", "blog"),
                new OrderParameter("elements.post_date", SortOrder.Descending)
                );

            var blogs = response.Items;

            return View(response.Items);
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(string urlSlug)
        {
            var response = await client.GetItemsAsync<Blog>(
                new EqualsFilter("elements.url_pattern", urlSlug),
                new EqualsFilter("system.type", "blog"),
                new DepthParameter(1)
            );

            var blog = response.Items[0];

            return View(blog);
```

Posts View:

```
@model Project.Models.Blog
    @foreach (var blog in Model)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor((vm) => blog)
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        {
            <div class="clear"></div>
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the error messages you are getting? If it's a problem with routing, could you please share your file/folder structure?

Comment: Are you using .NET MVC 5? Could you please share your route config?